# Using MailMerge in Django

Tags: django

How do you implement MailMerge in django instead of using EmailMessage?

Comment: You refer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521727/how-to-create-doc-files-using-templates-with-django-python/47259474#47259474

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to implement mail merge in Django is to use the [built-in template engine](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#using-the-template-system) with appropriate templates and models.